# Passport error when running sails through jxcore

Tags: javascript, sails.js, jxcore

I am trying to protect the code of my sailsjs project with jxp (from jxcore).
I've created the package successfully and install a bunch of modules (passport is one of them). All the installations went fine but when I run the application, I have the following error message:

```
luc@venus: /tmp/proj $ ~/Desktop/jx my_package.jx
/private/tmp/proj/config/passport.js.jx:10

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'serializeUser'
at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/proj/config/passport.js.jx:10:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:520:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..jx (module.js:1352:405)
at Module.load (module.js:359:33)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:333:12)
at Module.require (module.js:372:17)
at require (module.js:399:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/proj/config/passport.js:3:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:520:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:538:10)
```

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

When using the last version of jx (beta2), I now have the following error when running jx MYPROJ.jx

```
/Users/luc/proj1/node_modules/sails/node_modules/winston/lib/winston.js.jx:52
winston.loggers = new winston.Container();
```

Comment: have you defined the function `passport.serializeUser` somewhere in your `config/passport.js` file..??

Comment: yes it is defined. the application works fine when it's run with sails lift. When I use jx it gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

You just update it to latest version of JXcore, and it will work fine. I just tested a similar case without an issue.

Update

It seems that pkginfo module (one of the node modules winston uses), tries to access directory list inside the package which is limited due to protection.

Comment: what is the version you are using ?

Comment: I have latest b2.1.9.

Comment: I still have a problem (different from the previous one). I've added an update to the question.

Comment: are you able to run the project without packaging it? as far as I remember winston package had problems with node 10+

Comment: one more hint is that you may use 'jx install' instead 'npm install', most of the times it fixes the small problems with the packages

Comment: updated the answer, seems pkginfo is not supported for packaging

Comment: I've just tried with 'jx install', the installation seems ok. But when I run the app, I have the same error (the one linked to winston). Do you have a workaround in mind ? :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an Issue in JXCore which is fixed in upcoming release for circular requires which does winston use.

See https://github.com/Nubisa/jxdocs/issues/123 for more information.